# Fullscreen image width in img-tag

Tags: php, html, css

I'm using PHP snippet to add a simple image to top of my page, and now I'm trying to have it fullscreen (edge to edge).

Yet no matter what CSS I try, it never seems to work.

```
function add_custom_content(){ ?>
  <?php if ( is_home() ) : ?>
    <div class="custom-content x-container max width headerhero">
         <img src="...x.jpg" alt="X.com" /> 
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php }
add_action('x_before_view_global__index', 'add_custom_content');
```

And CSS is following:

```
.headerhero { 
min-height:100%;
min-width:100%;
height:auto;
width:auto;
margin:auto;
object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From what you're showing us your image has a `width` and `height` of `auto`. Apply to your image `width: 100vw` and `height: 100vh`. See example below

```css
body, div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/2000" alt="a random image">
</div>
```